# Recursion with list without using iteration(for,while)

Tags: list, recursion, nested, nested-lists

I need to work on a function that includes a nested list argument and i am not able to use for,while statements in my job.

For example  an input for my function is:

```
L = [ [1, 13.0, 0.5, 11.0, 6.0, 9.5, 2.5],
[-1, 6.0, 3.0, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 6.5],
[1, 0.5, 2.0, 8.5, 2.0, 8.5, 8.5, 0.5, 8.5],
[1, 3.5, 4.0, 0.7],
[-1, 8.5, 8.5, 5.5, 5.0, 5.5, 8.5, 8.5, 5.0] ]
```

as u see nested list. And without using for-while i want to work on the elements of this list

Like this:

```
     if len(L[0])==7:

           x= (L[0][1]+L[0][3]+L[0][5])/3
           y=(L[0][2]+L[0][4]+L[0][6])/3
```

and i want to go from 0 to end of the list but the length of the Input(List) is unknown.

So what is the case? How can i create a recursion here?

i mean i want to work on all elements of the list starting from L[0] to L[1],L[2]..... whatever given as input. Normally i can use "for" iteration but i am not allowed to use it. So can i create a base and increment it like in for statement?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you're trying to accomplish, but you might try using something like

```
if (gettype(L[0]) == 'array') { //do something }
```

Comment: I think u did not understand :D i mean i want to work on all elements of the list starting from L[0] to L[1],L[2]..... whatever given as input. Normally i can use for iteration but  i am not allowed to use it. So can i create a base and increment it like in for statement?